# SSRS report not showing data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSRS to develop a report. I've created a stored procedure on the server and I am accessing it through the report. Within SSMS, the stored procedure runs and returns data just fine. Also, within Visual Studio I run the debug version of the report and it outputs data just fine.

The problem arises when I deploy the report and try to run it in the web portal. It runs without any errors and displays the report header, but there is no data! I've tried creating a new report accessing the same stored procedure and the same thing happens. What could cause this?

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpenseClaimsSecretaries] 
@year integer,
@code varchar(MAX),
@dept integer
AS

BEGIN
SELECT        
    a_employee_number, 
    hd_employee_name, 
    a_claim_number, 
    a_template_code, 
    hd_claim_status, 
    SUM(dt_actual_amount) AS total
FROM            
    mu_live.dbo.ee_claim_master
WHERE        
    (hd_fiscal_year = @year) 
AND 
    (a_template_code LIKE (@code)) 
AND 
    (hd_department_code LIKE @dept)
GROUP BY 
    a_employee_number, 
    hd_employee_name, 
    a_claim_number, 
    a_template_code, 
    hd_claim_status
```

END

Comment: First thought is have you put some debug code that outputs before the data table you wanting to report on?  RS reports from the first returned table. If thats not the case I would run profiler and confirm the report is getting the parameter values you expect

Comment: I'm not well versed in using profiler, unfortunately. And I'm not sure how to implement the debug code you're talking about. Sorry for being a little dense, I swear I'm good at what I do! I've developed a lot of these reports but haven't seen this before.

Comment: Does the SP take parameters? Any chance you are not passing through what you expect? It would really be worth your while learning how to use SQL Profiler. There are many guides on the internet on how to do it.

Comment: Most probable cause is wrong parameter values so use SQL profiler and check what query is fired for report

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It does use parameters, there are three. I'm looking through the profiler dump and it appears to be passing the correct ones: `@Parameters=N'year=2014&code=2014-MILEAGE&dept=508'`

Comment: You are sending the whole URL string inside the parameter. You're not sending individual parameters. Are you parsing the URL inside your stored proc? Perhaps you should post your stored proc to clarify

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've added the procedure. The parameters are listed separately in my SSRS report, how could they be sent as one?

Comment: In that profiler dump you are passing one parameter, `@parameter` and it has three parameters mashed up in a single string. Something doesn't add up but its hard to tell what.